# Assigning different colors to variables in a barplot in R programming

Tags: r

I have this

```
test scores <- c(96, 71, 78, 95, 82, 61, 62, 68)
```

And I want to represent test scores above `80` in a barplot with red color and below `80` with blue color.

What I have tried:

```
testscores <- ifelse(testscores >=80, "blue", " red")
```

I an and error message

> Error: unexpected input in "testscores <- ifelse(testscores >=80, ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testscores <- c(96, 71, 78, 95, 82, 61, 62, 68)
cols <- ifelse(testscores >=80, "red", " blue")
barplot(testscores, col = cols )
```

This should work as intended?

[image]

Comment: Thank you heck1.. What if I want to attach the scores under each bars?

Answer (score 1):

```
testscores <- c(96, 71, 78, 95, 82, 61, 62, 68)
ifelse(testscores >=80, "blue", " red")
```

No problem.